# Issue with lstlisting inside semiverbatim

Tags: beamer

Code I got from [here...](http://inspirated.com/2010/03/08/using-overlays-for-source-code-listings-in-latex-beamer/comment-page-1#comment-122779)

When I run it, the output has line numbers broken, like it says 1, then from 3 to 6 and then 8 to 11... Any idea why?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\usepackage{pxfonts}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\lstset{language=python,
        numbers=left,
        numberstyle=\tiny,
        showstringspaces=false,
        aboveskip=-40pt,
        frame=leftline
        }

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{\texttt{parrot.py}}
\begin{semiverbatim}
\pause
\begin{lstlisting}
if __name__ == "__main":

\end{lstlisting}

\pause
\begin{lstlisting}[firstnumber=last]
    print "Oh yes, the, uh,
           the Norwegian Blue..."
    print "What's, uh...
           What's wrong with it? "

\end{lstlisting}

\pause
\begin{lstlisting}[firstnumber=last]
    print "I'll tell you what's wrong with it,
           my lad."
    print "'E's dead,
           that's what's wrong with it!"

\end{lstlisting}
\end{semiverbatim}
\end{frame}

\end{document
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are empty lines in those listings. A line number is assigned to each empty line, but that number is not printed. Try:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\usepackage{pxfonts}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}

\lstset{language=python,
        numbers=left,
        numberstyle=\tiny,
        showstringspaces=false,
        aboveskip=-40pt,
        frame=leftline
        }

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{\texttt{parrot.py}}
\begin{semiverbatim}
\pause
\begin{lstlisting}
if __name__ == "__main":
\end{lstlisting}

\pause
\begin{lstlisting}[firstnumber=last]
    print "Oh yes, the, uh,
           the Norwegian Blue..."
    print "What's, uh...
           What's wrong with it? "
\end{lstlisting}

\pause
\begin{lstlisting}[firstnumber=last]
    print "I'll tell you what's wrong with it,
           my lad."
    print "'E's dead,
           that's what's wrong with it!"
\end{lstlisting}
\end{semiverbatim}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]